# How to renew a singleton closed Stan (nats streaming) connection in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I have an application and I create and add the Stan connection with this extension method into `ServiceProvider`.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddStanClient(this IServiceCollection services, StanSettings settings)
{
    var stanOptions = StanOptions.GetDefaultOptions();
    var natsOptions = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();
    var stanClientId = $"{settings.ClientId}-{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    var stanClusterId = settings.ClusterId;

    natsOptions.Servers = settings.NatsServers.ToArray();
    natsOptions.AllowReconnect = true;
    natsOptions.MaxReconnect = Options.ReconnectForever;
    natsOptions.PingInterval = 2000;
    natsOptions.MaxPingsOut = 2;
    natsOptions.ReconnectWait = 1000;
    natsOptions.Timeout = 4000;

    IStanConnection stanConnection = new StanConnectionFactory().CreateConnection(stanClusterId, stanClientId, stanOptions);

    natsOptions.ClosedEventHandler += (object sender, ConnEventArgs arg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"connection lost on connection {arg.Conn.ConnectedId}" +
                                  $"{Environment.NewLine} {arg.Error.StackTrace}");
            };

    natsOptions.ReconnectedEventHandler += (object sender, ConnEventArgs arg) => {
                stanOptions.NatsConn = arg.Conn; 
                //services.Remove(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStanConnection), stanConnection));
                stanConnection = new StanConnectionFactory().CreateConnection(stanClusterId, stanClientId, stanOptions);

                services.AddSingleton<IStanConnection>(stanConnection);

                Console.WriteLine($"Connection recovered by connection id {arg.Conn.ConnectedId}");
        }; 
            
    stanOptions.NatsConn = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection(natsOptions);
    stanOptions.ConnectionLostEventHandler += (object sender, StanConnLostHandlerArgs arg) => {
            Console.WriteLine($"connection lost on connection {arg.Connection.NATSConnection.ConnectedId}" +
            $"{Environment.NewLine} {arg.ConnectionException.StackTrace}"); 
        };
            
    services.AddSingleton<IStanConnection>(stanConnection);

    return services;
}
```

When it loses the connection to the nats streaming server for 15 seconds it is in reconnecting mode and if the connection works properly again my application can publish messages without any problem.

But after 15 seconds, I will get the connection closed error, and reconnecting to the server cannot fix anything and I will get the connection closed error until I restart my application.

It can make things more clear that the **nats** connection will connect again but the **Stan** connection cannot update its connection status.

My stan client version is 0.3.0.

How can I renew this connection or configure it to reconnect whenever it fount the serve?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a singleton that represents a connection, _Stan_ or otherwise due to the fact that it may need to be torn down and re-created.  DI-client code should refer to the connection factory and _request a connection_ as required and provide them the ability to fetch another one if it faults. If you must have a singleton, consider marking the connection factory as so.

Comment: If I create it as transient and it throws the clientId is registered already exception, and no change in behavior if I create the connection by scope

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 you can't fix a fault-handling problem using DI. This isn't about the lifecycle of a connection, it's about handling a connection fault. You need to modify your code to actually handle the fault and reconnect, or use a library like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to specify retry policies. If `nats` fails to reconnect automatically when it should, you have a `nats` problem, not a DI problem

Comment: I know, I need a workaround about renewing the connection.